# How should I respond to an IL 2012 "Notice of Proposed Tax Due"?

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, illinois

I received today a "Notice of Proposed Tax Due" for Illinois, alleging:

```
Tax Due: $738.00
Penalty Due: $111.00
Interest Due: $34.00
```

This seems suspicious to me; I have been meticulous with taxes and the Illinois tax form applicable to me is very simple.

What are my next best steps to find out if the debt has been fabricated and address this?

Comment: was this sent via mail, or email? Is  there any other info on the notice?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, such notices are often incorrect (having received one recently from the IRS for > 20,000).  This requires some work, but shouldn't be a big deal.

The form itself with that comes with it should specify which line items they disagree with, typically a side-by-side of "what you wrote" and "what it should be".  If it doesn't, call the state to find out more information.

After reviewing their information in detail, if you disagree, you will need to send a response.  If you can understand the error they made, then you can refute it.  If not, you may need to call them again.  (In my case it was an IRA recharacterization they misunderstood, due to not reading an attachment or misplacing a form they should have gotten.)

In your response, you should send them relevant documents, including a letter you write explaining the argument and how it fits in.  These documents should include both things that they typically ask you to submit as well as things that they don't.  Remember, the burden of proof falls on you (i.e., you are guilty until proven innocent.)

In my case, the IRS's response was to retract the bill in full.